# Use image inside library in Angular

Tags: angular, assets

I want to build an Angular library that provides a component  that contains an image.

So far I was able to add the image as an asset to the library. The `dist` folder has currently the following structure:

```
dist/my-lib
  +-- assets
  |   +-- myimage.png
  +-- esm2020
  +-- fesm2015
  +-- fesm2020
  +-- lib
  |   +-- test
  |   |   +-- test.component.d.ts
  |   +-- my-lib.module.d.ts
  +-- index.d.ts
  +-- package.json
  +-- public-api.d.ts
```

I can display the component `test` in an example application, but the image does not show up. The component template contains the following code:

```
<p>library works!</p>
<img src="./assets/myimage.png" />
```

Does anybody knows how to set the image source path properly or how I have to configure my library so that the image `myimage.png` will show up in the component `test`?

Thank's
Michael

Comment: The image path `../../assets/9024765_lock_key_light.png` doesn't work either.

Comment: Can you try without the `assets` prefix?

Comment: I tried <img src="myimage.png"> and <img src="./myimage.png">. The result was the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove ./ from path. Your path should be assets/myimage.png

Comment: I also tried `assets/myimgage.png` and other. I tested also relative path from component `.ts` file to the assets folder in the corresponding `node_modules`. I tested the relative path from componnets `d.ts` (build files) to the assets folder in `dist` folder. Nothing works.

As far as I now, you can use the `assets` notation without `./` only because there should be an `assets` entry in the `angular.json`. But per convention `assets` filed is not allowed for libraries inside the `angular.json`.

Comment: Currently I can display the library assets within a component of the target applikation. This needs a corresponding entry in the `angular.json`. But I can't display the assets within a library component directly, because `assets` field does not exist for library projects. It seems that there is no way to display library assets directly inside a library component :-(